# League based on trophies

Tags: clash-of-clans

How am I still in Crystal III League if the minimum trophies for crystal are 2000 while I just have 1981  trophies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it works like  this:

Crystal III

Trophy range: 2000 - 2199

Demoted to a lower league if trophy count drops to 1900

Promoted to a higher league if trophy count rises to 2200

https://forum.supercell.com/showthread.php/37226-How-Leagues-work

Comment: I believe this is the correct answer based on my experience. I always drop a league when I'm 100 trophies or more below the threshold for joining the league I was originally in.

Comment: Actually yeah I just experienced the same yesterday.. thanks @Ellesedil

Answer (score 1):

When you are placed in a league, you are in that league until you graduate or flunk. You graduate by gaining the required number of trophies for the next league, and you flunk by dropping below the current #100 player in your league OR dropping below 100 trophies less than the required number for your current league.

Source: Personal experience, @Ellesedil

Comment: Do you really drop leagues if you drop out of the top 100? I've always noticed my league decreases when I drop 100 trophies below the minimum threshold for joining the league in the first place. For example, if I need 2400 trophies for Crystal 1, and I drop down to 2300 trophies or less, I'll drop down to Crystal 2.

Comment: You might be right, but then both conditions are in place. Editing. Just never happened to me before!